# "Move" changeset in wrong TFS branch

Tags: tfs

Suppose that I check-in a change in the wrong TFS branch. I need to get my changes to a different branch then somehow eliminate those changes from the wrong branch. Can this be accomplished without resorting to selective copy/pasting? Eventually I *do* want my changes in the branch I mistakenly added them to... just not yet.

If I had not checked in the changes, I could shelve them, then [use tfpt to unshelve into a different branch](http://dimarzionist.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/tfs-2010-hot-to-unshelve-to-a-different-branch/). But that won't work here, since I've already checked the changes in.

---

Example:

I have an environment with a MAIN and DEVELOPMENT branch. I need to create a new module, called Buzzsaw. I have a solution open and hack away on my changes. Then I check them in. Oops. I realize that I just checked my module into MAIN, but it should have been checked into DEVELOPMENT. I could rollback the mistaken changeset, but then I need to apply my changes to DEVELOPMENT manually. Most of the affected files are the same between the branches, but there are enough differences that I'd rather not copy/paste my changes.

I could merge my changes from MAIN to DEV, then rollback MAIN. But now it is difficult to bring the changes back to MAIN when I really do want them present (merging DEV to MAIN now doesn't move that changeset, since it was already merged).

---

What can I do? Is there a fairly clean way to accomplish this?

Comment: are you sure about that: "merging DEV to MAIN now doesn't move that changeset, since it was already merged" ?

Comment: It's possible that I'm doing something wrong, but I am nearly sure. If file A on branch I is in changeset 1 and I merge, file A on branch II is in changeset 2. Now, if I ask TFS to merge II to I, there are no pending changes. Even if I commit A' on I as changeset 3, merging II to I will have no pending changesets.

Comment: Ok, but if you do a rollback of the changeset 1 in I, then are you still unable to merge back from II to I ?

Comment: You are correct. I was sure that I've tried that in the past, but I either did it wrong and didn't really try it. Thanks! If you expand your comment slightly as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: :) in fact I already had my answer typed, all I needed was to publish it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Merge from the wrong branch to the correct one, then do an [changeset rollback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194956%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the one in the wrong branch.

Whenever you need, you still can merge back the changeset from the correct branch to the wrong one.

Comment: I merged from the wrong branch to the correct one, then rolled back my changes on the wrong branch. Finally, I did a merge discard of the rollbacks so that they would not accidentally be integrated into the correct branch.

Answer (score 3):

You can "shelve" the changes in the wrong branch and [unshelve them into the correct one](http://dimarzionist.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/tfs-2010-hot-to-unshelve-to-a-different-branch/).

Comment: I thought about this too. The problem here is that the changes have already been checked in. I don't think it's possible to get those changes into a shelveset. To be clear: this would work great if the Buzzsaw changes had not already been checked into MAIN.